# Thunderbird Add-On: Compose Message - Create a sidebar for the add-on?

Tags: mozilla, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

Is there a way to create a sidebar for the add-on? I saw how to add a panel at the bottom of the email using vbox (but I guess that's not the way to do it in the new architecture of Thunderbird add-ons). I want to add a sidebar panel on the right side. Changing to hbox does not work. Is this possible? This is in order to create an add-on that looks over the text of the email you compose and give insights in a sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure (I have not tried), but for the newest versions of Thunderbird that only run Webextensions (78+), I believe you should look at **the `composeScripts` API** (see [documentation](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/78/composeScripts.html)). It should allow you to inject CSS stylesheets and JS scripts into the composing window. From there you should be able to edit the DOM, add your sidebar (basically a DIV floating to the right of the page I suppose) and the relevant actions.

Comment: Can you actually change the Thunderbird's composing window with these functions? Any example somewhere for a demo add-on that does that?

Comment: Pretty sure we can, although I don't know any add-on that does it (but then I don't know all add-ons). Best pointers I have would be API doc, [this sample](https://github.com/thundernest/sample-extensions/blob/master/composeBody/background.js) using another API [`composeAction`](https://thunderbird-webextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/composeAction.html) (change compose window but through an “action” (a button to click)), and `composeScripts`-related tests [from comm-central](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/file/tip/mail/components/extensions/test/browser/browser_ext_composeScripts.js).